# mount ecryptfs without sudo

Tags: mount, fstab, ecryptfs

I am using the following script to mount an ecryptfs directory (from [How To Recover Synology encrypted folders in Linux](http://robertcastle.com/2012/10/howto-recover-synology-encrypted-folders-in-linux/)).

```
tty -echo
read -p "Enter passphrase: " PASS; echo
stty echo

sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes,passwd=$PASS $1 $2
```

How can I do this without sudo as normal user?

Comment: Why not run it with sudo  ? you only need to add the line `myuser  ALL=/usr/local/bin/mount-my-ecryptfs  NOPASSWD: ALL` to the sudoers file.

Comment: or use a fuse file-system

Comment: @richard, Rabin Would be great, if you would add your suggestions as additional answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to generate an fstab entry as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Auto-mounting_2

Using the mount command one can get  the correct mount options and add this to the fstab file

```
/path/to/encrypted/dir /path/to/decrypted/dir ecryptfs              noauto,user,rw,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=XY,ecryptfs_sig=XY,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0    0
```

Where XY has to be replaced by the correct signature (printed by mount).

Before mounting one has to add the passphrase to the keyring, for example

```
printf "%s" "mypassword" | ecryptfs-add-passphrase
```

Then it is possible to mount the volume via:

```
mount -i /path/to/decrypted/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using fuse: user mode file-system. It allows ordinary users to mount file-systems. If there is a fuse file system available.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this? I've been trying to remove sudo by using `unshare` (`unshare -m --map-root-user`) but it still fails to mount, giving a 'Operation not permitted'.

Comment: @dangeroushobo `unshare` is a different question. However you could edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow a specific `command args`. Or search for a fuse file-system, that will do what you want. or something else.